# Nginx serving wrong certificate and site only when access from particular IP

Tags: nginx

I have a wordpress site set up on NGINX with a valid certificate from certbot where I am able to see it from every IP except my home IP.  When I use proxies or a different internet connection, the wordpress site is displayed correctly.  I can also access the site with just HTTP and can see it from every IP except my home IP.  I bypassed wordpress and made a simple echo PHP file to make sure that no plugin was causing the problem.  Still, the echo shows up everywhere except from my home IP address.  My conclusion is that Nginx is somehow restricting my IP, but I have no idea of where to start looking for this at.  Are there any ideas about what might be going on?  I do not have fail2ban installed nor do I have any known firewall rules that would cause this.  Any ideas as to what is going on?

In the nginx log, the error states:
`access forbidden by rule, client: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx`

However, there are no set rules for something like this in the config that i see:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name <redacted>;
    root /var/www/<redacted>;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate <redacted>;
    ssl_certificate_key <redacted>;
    include <redacted>;
    ssl_dhparam <redacted>; 

}
```

Comment: Is the wordpress site also on the same home IP?

Comment: @RichardSmith No.That would be too easy. :)